# What is the convergence behaviour for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ with $z\in\mathbb{C},|z|=1$ and $0 < d \leq 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

How can I prove that for $d>1$ the series converges absolutely, I only know that for $d\leq 0$ the series diverges (In both cases under the assumption that $|z|=1$) What can I say for the other choices for $d$  left.

Is there  a way to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}$ converges absolutely for $d>1$ respectively $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ for $d>1$ and $|z|=1$ without using the integral test?

Comment: "Is there  a way to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}$ converges absolutely for $d>1$" -- You will want to look into the topic of $p$-series. (They typically have $p$ for the exponent here, not $d$.)

Comment: @T.Bongers The title of my last question is too general I have made this new question which deals with my core problem

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thank youI forgot about the cauchy-condensation test. Can you say something about my question in the title?

Comment: For $0\le d\le 1$ and $z=1$, the series diverges.  For $|z|\lt 1$, the series is absolutely convergent.  In the$|z|=1$ case, $z=1$ is a pole of the function, so the radius of convergence $=1$.

Comment: You have *Hadamard's formula* to find the radius of convergence. It seems to be $1$ whatever $d$.

Comment: I know that the radius of convergence is $1$ .But for $z=-1$ and $d=1$ the series is absolutely convergent, is it possible to proof that the convergencebehaviour of the series depends on $z$ with $|z|=1$ if $d<0\leq 1$. I.e. can I prove the existence of a convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\epsilon}z^n,|z|=1$?